# check network connectivity in phonegap application on android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

checkConnection();
```

I wrote this code and checked there is always Cell 3G connection coming with result even if i disconnect it from LAN. I am testing application on android sdk. Let me know if there is any setting i need to change